# Displace output from formula into another cell - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like the array result of a formula to be displaced/displayed somewhere else. In this instance it should appear down a row.

For this case, it can be done by padding out the first row of a wrap around array, but it's not very pretty and is not dynamic. (It must be ammended if the number of array columns changes.)

`={"","","","";query(A1:D5)}`

Is there a better more generic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
={INDEX(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(A:D))/0)); QUERY(A1:D5)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with IFERROR(.../0) combined with SEQUENCE(), COLUMN() or ROW().

Something along the lines of

```
=arrayformula({iferror(sequence(1,columns(A1:D5))/0);query(A1:D5)})
```

Comment: This needs a little explanation please.

Comment: I understand . `sequence(1,columns(A1:D5))`  creates an array with a single row with the right number of cells.  Is `IFERROR(.../0)` a method to empty the cells?

Comment: Yes. Anything divided by 0 returns an error and IFERROR() turns the error into a blank cell.